# List NX targets

Tags: node.js, build, command-line-interface, nrwl-nx

I can't find a command that lists the available NX targets from the command line. I'd expect something like `nx list`, but that lists plugins, not targets.

Currently the only way I can find what targets I can run is to manually inspect `project.json`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess until https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/18160 gets implemented, a way to list all the targets from command line is by running `jq` - either per project, or from NX workspace root - with a command similar to:

`jq -r '.name, (.targets | keys)' **/project.json`